# Convert String in to Enum Without knowing it's type in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I am facing a problem. I have set of some enum in my app. Like

```
public enum EnmSection
{
    Section1,
    Section2,
    Section3
}

public enum Section1
{
    TestA,
    TestB
}

public enum Section2
{
    Test1,
    Test2
}
```

`EnmSection` is main enum which contains the other enum(as string) which are declared below it. Now i have to fill the values of `EnmSection` in a drop-down.I have done it.
Like this...

```
drpSectionType.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnmSection));
drpSectionType.DataBind();
```

Now my drop-down has values: `Section1,Section2,Section3`

Problem is:

I have another drop-down `drpSubSection`. Now i want to fill this drop-down whatever i have selected in the `drpSectionType`.

for ex If I selected Section1 in drpSectionType then drpSubsection should contain the value
`TestA,TestB`. Like this:

```
protected void drpSectionType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strType = drpSectionType.SelectedValue;
    drpSubsection.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof());
    drpSubsection.DataBind();
}
```

Here `typeof()` is expecting the enum.But i am getting selected value as string. How can i achieve this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What if you reference an assembly that contains another enum with a value named `Section1`?

You'll just have to try all the enums you care about, one at a time, and see which one works. You'll probably want to use `Enum.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

```
drpSubsection.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(Type.GetType("Your.Namespace." + strType));
```

If the enums are in another assembly, (i.e. they're not in mscorlib or the current assembly) you'll need to provide the [`AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx).  The easiest way to get this will be to look at `typeof(Section1).AssemblyQualifiedName`, then modify your code to include all the necessary parts.  The code will look something like this when you're done:

```
drpSubsection.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(Type.GetType("Your.Namespace." + strType + ", MyAssembly, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b17a5c561934e089"));
```

Comment: Not working. It gives me error:- Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: enumType

Comment: That means that Type.GetType isn't finding the type.  Are you sure you've got the namespace of the enum in there correctly?

Comment: If the types are in another assembly, you'll need to provide the assembly-qualified name, instead of just what I've shown there.  I'll edit my answer to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, but you have to do some exception handling:

```
protected void drpSectionType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{    
  string strType = drpSectionType.SelectedValue;    
  EnmSection section = (EnmSection)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnmSection), strType);
  drpSubsection.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(section));     
  drpSubsection.DataBind();

 }
```

Comment: Not working. I can't able to aceess section enum in typeof() --->  Enum.GetNames(typeof(section));

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit over the top but it would work if you bind bind Arrays of IEnumItem to your drop down and set it up to show their display text.

```
public interface IEnumBase
{
  IEnumItem[] Items { get; }
}

public interface IEnumItem : IEnumBase
{
  string DisplayText { get; }
}

public class EnumItem : IEnumItem
{
  public string DisplayText { get; set; }
  public IEnumItem[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class EnmSections : IEnumBase
{
  public IEnumItem[] Items { get; private set; }

  public EnmSections()
  {
    Items = new IEnumItem[]
    {
      new EnumItem
      {
        DisplayText = "Section1",
        Items = new IEnumItem[]
        {
          new EnumItem { DisplayText = "TestA" },
          new EnumItem { DisplayText = "TestB" }
        }
      },
      new EnumItem
      {
        DisplayText = "Section2",
        Items = new IEnumItem[]
        {
          new EnumItem { DisplayText = "Test1" },
          new EnumItem { DisplayText = "Test2" }
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```